# How to Setdata to new Appdomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

How to SetData to new created AppDomain. When i DoCallBack to my testFunc i receive "**System.NullReferenceException**" exception. What i do wrong?

```
var client = "test";
var engine = 123;

AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("newDomain");

appDomain.SetData("client", client);
appDomain.SetData("engine", engine);

appDomain.DoCallBack(testFunc);

 private void testFunc()
 {
    var client = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("client");
    var engine = (int)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("engine");

    Console.WriteLine("client: " + client);
    Console.WriteLine("engine: " + engine);
 }
```

Setting vars globaly for AppDomain don't change anathing, same error.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("client", client);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("engine", engine);
```

**P.S.**
I receive System.NullReferenceException, because AppDomain can't find that vars that i was setup before DoCallBack. So how to setup them in right way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope, this is not.

Comment: I have created a Console app, copied the provided code and everything is working as you'd expect.

Comment: @SLI Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, i rethink my code and rewrite it.

Comment: @SLI Why? Did the answer not help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you show us the correct code then you can't set non-static and without instance method to  `DoCallBack()`.

The method should be a static:

```
private static void testFunc()
 {
    var client = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("client");
    var engine = (int)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("engine");

    Console.WriteLine("client: " + client);
    Console.WriteLine("engine: " + engine);
 }
```

or you have to create a instance before pass into `DoCallBack()`

```
var instance = new Program();
appDomain.DoCallBack(instance.testFunc);
```